# Reactable table sorting on checkboxes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using Reactable table in my react app and my columns are custom ones. Whilst sorting is basically working in regards that the order changes, the problem I am seeing is with check boxes. I have a column of checkboxes and the sort order is not keeping the checked boxes in the sort, in other words the sort order is lost. I have tried adding the column to the sort but this does not work.

Has anyone come across this problem and could help me

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add value attribute with some info of the row object to the `<Td>` tag ?

This will look at like this

```
<Td column="columnCheck" value="someValue"><CheckboxComponent /></Td>
```

also, you can specify a custom sort function.

you can find more info in the documentation

https://github.com/glittershark/reactable

I hope that works for you.